# How can Categories in SharePoint modern site can be managed

Tags: sharepoint, office365, mediawiki

We have a project to migrate a site from MediaWiki to a SharePoint modern page. We easily conducted a migration using a Metalogix tool.

However, from a design perspective, what is the best way to manage Categories in the SharePoint modern site, so that the Category functionality would be similar to the Category functionality in MediaWiki (Wikipedia)

Should we use SharePoint Lists for this functionality, or should we use tagging?

Thank you very much in advance for your helpful answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer here at this link

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/how-can-categories-in-sharepoint-modern-site-be-managed/m-p/1176713

> I would be inclined to use tagging through a custom site column in the
>   "Site Pages" library. On the page, you can display tag using the "Page
>   properties" web part and finally tie it all together using the
>   "Highlighted content" web part filtered on the tag.